# Rostopic node in launch files

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to add a rostopic -pub node into a launch file, but I don't know what I have to put in the launch file command line.

I guess this has to be the structure:

`<node pkg="rostopic" type="pub" name="arbitrary_name" args=" /pkg_topic pkg_executable_file/message" output="screen"/>`

Thank you for your comments.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216036/rostopic-node-in-launch-files/) by [palfaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/23109/palfaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-08-18

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually the binary, i.e., `type` is also `rostopic`. The `pub` is just an argument passed to that. So, if you just move the `pub` to args, it should work:

```
<node pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" name="arbitrary_name" args="pub /pkg_topic pkg_executable_file/message" output="screen"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2021-04-07**:
one example could also be `args="pub /my_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 50"`. In this case I am publishing an `std_msgs/Float64` with `data = 50` to topic `/my_controller/command` even though I didn't type `data`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use it like this:

```
<node pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" name="default_camera_info" args="pub /openni2_grabber/camera/rgb/camera_info sensor_msgs/CameraInfo --latch --file=$(find openni2_grabber)/launch/default_high.camera_info" output="screen"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) with karma: 311 on 2018-05-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1